# Insert comment chars "//" at leftmost position on each line

Tags: emacs, comments

1 thing about comment-region I want to change or write a custom function.

Comment-region inserts the "//" at the first non-white-space position, not the leftmost column.

I want the "//" to be inserted at column 0 of each line aka the leftmost position. How?

Update: I found this function seems to be the culprit. Can this be modified to insert at column 0 instead of at first non-white-space column?

```
(defun my-comment-current-line ()
(interactive)
(beginning-of-line 1)
(insert "//")
)
```

Thanks, Mike

Answer (score 1):

You want to customize `comment-style`.  E.g.

```
(setq comment-style 'plain)
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it

```
(defun my-comment-current-line ()
(interactive)
(move-beginning-of-line 1)
(insert "//")
)
```